# Apigee Usergrid: Which data structure amongst the two here is better?

Tags: cassandra, apigee, usergrid

I am using Apigee Usergrid which user Cassandra internally. While storing data I have the following predicament.

Do I store data like this:

```
[{
"portlet": "personal_information",
"fields": [{
    "id": "first_name",

    "text": {
        "en_us": "First Name",
        "de_de": "First Name"
    }
}, {
    "id": "salutation",

    "text": {
        "en_us": "Salutation",
        "de_de": "Salutation"
    }
}, {
    "id": "marital_status",

    "text": {
        "en_us": "Marital Status",
        "de_de": "Marital Status"
    }
}, {
    "id": "native_preferred_lang",
    "text": {
        "en_us": "Preferred Lang",
        "de_de": "Preferred Lang"
    }
}]
```

}]

or this

```
    [{
        "id": "first_name",
        "portlet": "personal_information",
        "text": {
            "en_us": "First Name",
            "de_de": "First Name"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "salutation",
        "portlet": "personal_information",
        "text": {
            "en_us": "Salutation",
            "de_de": "Salutation"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "marital_status",
        "portlet": "personal_information",
        "text": {
            "en_us": "Marital Status",
            "de_de": "Marital Status"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "native_preferred_lang",
        "portlet": "personal_information",
        "text": {
            "en_us": "Preferred Lang",
            "de_de": "Preferred Lang"
        }
         }]
```

This is probably relevant to all no-sql databases. What's data format is more efficient?

Comment: For Cassandra, "efficient" depends on your query patterns.  Are you going to be querying users for specific subjects like marital status, first name, or salutation?  Or are you just going to query a user's personal information, and sort-out the subject matter on the client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Usergrid 2.x we use ElasticSearch for indexing so between these two structures there should be no functional difference.

In Usergrid 1.x we denormalize the entities and use an indexing scheme on top of Cassandra, so they are likely equally performant.

That said, you should test and ensure this, as with any software/solution.

Comment: What version does Apigee BaaS use?

Comment: api.usergrid.com uses 1.0.  Apigee customers are in process of being migrated to 2.x